# Trigger an EBS Volume Events in EC2 Events to send an email notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, triggers, amazon-ebs, aws-event-bridge

I want to send an email notification when I receive an event from the "EBS Volume Event", namely "io-performance:degraded".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdEiJ.png)

I tried with EventBridge but it seems the event pattern doesn't support the "io-performance" event. Is there any other way? Please help me.

Comment: good question, there seems to be no event for `EBS Volume Event`. The closest I could find is creating a CloudWatch Alarm and then use `CloudWatch Alarm State Change`. It would be more cost than just using CloudWatch Alarm in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you tell me more about CloudWatch Alarm State Change in my case?